# how to paginate object array laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

when i try to paginate results passed from the logged in user I get the error:

```
$message = Auth::user()->Notifications()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()
        ->groupBy(function($date) {
            return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('M d'); // grouping by day
        })
        ->paginate(2);
```

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate()

what is the problem and how can I paginate my object array?

Comment: this is a __spaghetti code__ read the documentation first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$message = Auth::user()->Notifications()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->groupBy(function($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('M d'); // grouping by day
    })->paginate(2);
```

the paginate method needs to be the last element in the chain like->get()

// edit: As stated here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination

> Note: Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database manually and use Paginator::make.

This could also be helpful: http://www.jenssegers.be/blog/57/laravel-pagination-with-grouping-and-eager-loading

Comment: i tried but got many errors: first grammar.php

strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Hmm, you are using a reserved keyword somewhere. Have you tried paginate without the groupBy? (Just for a test)

Comment: yes without groupBy all good, but how to group my table by date and time? i need to group like this https://jsfiddle.net/umpr84v2/ thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course you get the error as `groupBy` returns an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. You would need to do something like

```
$messages = Auth::user()->Notifications()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(2);

$messages->setItems($messages->groupBy(function($date) {
            return $date->created_at->format('M d'); // grouping by day
        }));
```

This way you set up new items in your pagination object which are grouped results from database.

Comment: now pagination showing and i dont get error, but notifications table emty. I dont give array maybe. its my blade https://jsfiddle.net/cu53m9cc/ thanks

Comment: Try to dump your results using ```messsages->getItems()->toArray()``` and see what is the structure. Then you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: nothing, empty too. than im dumping, got many info and browser not load to the end

Comment: So move the code which groups by your items:
```$test = $messages->groupBy(function($date) {
            return $date->created_at->format('M d'); // grouping by day
        })``` and dump it. See if it returns correct results. put it after ```paginate(2);```

Comment: var_dump its fine i got array, but than `$test = $message->groupBy(function($date) {
            return $date->created_at->format('M d');
        })->paginate(2);`

i got Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Collection::paginate()

Comment: Not sure what are you asking for now. Basically what I see is that you should have 2 level array, outer array should have date as key and actual array of notifications as value. So you should iterate twice over this arrays. Check this: http://pastebin.com/fMCne5px

Comment: array is fine, but with this foreach i got html but empty information, http://pastebin.com/wGUDKu8J